# .htaccess redirect http and https subdomain to other domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have subdomain: subdomain.example.com

I would like to redirect http and https to another domain

```
 http://subdomain.example.com --> https://subdomain.exampleNew.com
 https://subdomain.example.com --> https://subdomain.exampleNew.com
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Currently I have only:

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain.example.com$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://subdomain.exampleNew.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: So what's the actual problem?

Comment: You rule should work fine as shown.

Comment: You are right, that was diffrent problem, my domain .example.com doesn't have ssl and when entering  https://subdomain.example.com there was ssl error. Now I know that httacces isn't fired before ssl check.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retain the http/https status, the status needs to be captured first and then passed to the rule as `%1`. Use the following instead:

```bash
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http%1://subdomain.exampleNew.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```